# Good way to get streaming Twitter data using Apache Storm?

Tags: twitter, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I'm building a Twitter crawler system. Requirement is to crawl both Twitter Profile and Twitter Streaming. There's a project manager which puts all projects (1 project is a Twitter profile, or a keyword for Twitter Streaming) into Kafka. Then Storm will read from Kafka to get project metadata and start to run. The project manager will check all projects periodically and eventually restart the project (by putting data into Kafka), so every project has the latest data. I have a couple of questions:

- Since we need to keep a connection to Twitter Streaming, we cannot let a Bolt run for a very long time for the Twitter streaming project. Can you suggest a good way to do this, like implement a separate process for crawling?
- Another question is about tokens. We want each access token to run on one server only in order to improve stability and prevent reaching the rate limit too soon. When a project (tuple) starts to be processed in Storm, it would be assigned an access token of its supervisor IP. Is there any good solution for this? Someone recommends me to use Zookeeper to assign access token but I'm not sure if it's a good way and how to implement?